# How to get a list after each discovered device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using this function to scan BLE devices and save then into a list.

```
    public BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                if(aDevices.size() > 0) {

                    boolean isNewItem = true;

                    for (int i = 0; i < aDevices.size(); i++) {
                        if (aDevices.get(i).getMacAddress().equals(device.getAddress())) {
                            isNewItem = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(isNewItem) {
                        aDevices.add(new BluetoothLE(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), rssi, device));
                    }
                }else{
                    aDevices.add(new BluetoothLE(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), rssi, device));
                }
                
            }
        });

    }
    
};
```

And using this function to get a a list:

```
        public ArrayList<BluetoothLE> getListDevices(){
    return aDevices;
}
```

But, I want to get the list after each  `aDevices.add()` inside the thread. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an instance of ObservableArrayList and provide it with an implementation of OnListChangedCallback that is notified on each change instead of the ArrayList you are currently using.

```
public class MyCallback extends ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList> {

public void onChanged(ObservableList sender) {
    Log.i(tag, "list changed");
}

public void onItemRangeChanged(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    Log.i(tag, "item range changed");
}

public void onItemRangeInserted(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    Log.i(tag, "item range inserted");
}

public void onItemRangeMoved(ObservableList sender, int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount)  {
    Log.i(tag, "item range moved");
}

public void onItemRangeRemoved(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount)  {
    Log.i(tag, "item range removed");
}
}


ObservableArrayList list = new ObservableArrayList();
list.addOnListChangedCallback(new MyCallback());
...
list.add(element);
```

Comment: If you accept this question, please close the question.